# PHP 7 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.1

Before anyone mark my question as duplicate, I wish to clarify that my case is unique and specific to PHP 7 (I use PHP 7.1.1 in UniformServer).  I have seen all other similar questions here and they did not work for me.

I had a working code as below:

In class constructor:

```
$this->fldSection = "header";
```

down below in another function:

```
$_ENV['validate'][$this->fldSection][$this->name] = $params;
```

This is working fine in PHP 5.6.  However this gives the infamous "Cannot use string offset as an array.." error in PHP 7.1.1 for `$this->fldSection = 'header'` when it is set in the `$_ENV` variable

All my variables are dynamically filled.  Is there a different/better way to accomplish this in PHP 7.1.1?

Comment: I suspect that either `$_ENV['validate']` is a string or `$_ENV['validate'][$this->fldSection]` is a string

Comment: I did a dump of $_ENV and that is an array.  ($_ENV is actually a standard PHP global array).  The info I came across online suggest that it is because `$this->fldSection` is defined as text ("header") which is later being used as an array key.  But this code works flawlessly in PHP 5.6.  I'm trying to understand what changed in 7.1 to this regard and how to mitigate this.

Comment: @Ravi can you provide var_dump of `$_ENV`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked the reason for this issue. I'm using the super-global `$_ENV` to store my values and trying to assign variable-variables to it.  However from PHP documentation I find that variable-variables are ***not*** supported on super-globals. I changed the variable to `$GLOBAL` instead of `$_ENV` (like below) and it worked.

```
$GLOBAL['validate'][$this->fldSection][$this->name] = $params;
```

I'm not sure why it worked on 5.6 and not on 7.1.  I guess PHP has probably started enforcing those rules strictly only from v7.